# The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.0 on TFS 2015 build

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.2, asp.net-core-3.0

I am migrating an existing **ASP.NET Core** 2.2 web app to 3.0. I've updated the .csproj file and all references to support 3.0. Everything compiles on my dev machine, but when I try to build the app on the build server (TFS 2015 with the SDK / runtimes for **ASP.NET Core** 3.0) I get this error.

```
The current .NET SDK does not support targeting .NET Core 3.0. Either target .NET Core 2.2 or lower, or use a version of the .NET SDK that supports .NET Core 3.0
```

[image]

I have correctly referenced the **ASP.NET Core** framework in the .csproj

[image]

Here are my project dependencies from my Visual Studio project.

[image]

[image]

Why does **MSBUILD** still try to reference **ASP.NET Core** 2.2 when everything now references 3.0?

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation the problem was I didn't have the correct version of MSBUILD on the build server. As ASP.NET Core 3.0 only runs on VS2019 you therefore need MSBUILD for VS2019. After installing this on the build server the problem has now been resolved.